# prove that "closed and bounded" implies "compact" in a finite dimensional normed space

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I'm trying to prove that "closed and bounded" is equivalent to "compact" in a finite dimensional normed space using the following lemma:
Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be linealy independent vectors in a normed space, then there is a positive real number $c$ such that for every choice of scalars $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n$, we have $\parallel\alpha_1 x_1+...+\alpha_n x_n\parallel\geq c(|\alpha_1|+...+|\alpha_n|)$.

Here is my attempt and I need some help to finish it.

Let $e_1,...,e_n$ be a basis for $X$, let $M$ be a closed and bounded subset in $X$, and let $\{x_k\}$ be a sequence in $M$.

Then we there are scalars in the field such that

$x_1=\alpha_1^{(1)}e_1+\alpha_2^{(1)}e_2+...+\alpha_n^{(1)}e_n$,

$x_2=\alpha_1^{(2)}e_1+\alpha_2^{(2)}e_2+...+\alpha_n^{(2)}e_n$,

...

$x_k=\alpha_1^{(k)}e_1+\alpha_2^{(k)}e_2+...+\alpha_n^{(k)}e_n$,

...

In the next step, I was able to show (using the lemma above and the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem) that all these sequences $(\alpha_1^{(1)},\alpha_1^{(2)},...,\alpha_1^{(k)},...), (\alpha_2^{(1)},\alpha_2^{(2)},...,\alpha_2^{(k)},...),...,(\alpha_n^{(1)},\alpha_n^{(2)},...,\alpha_n^{(k)},...)$ contain a convergent subsequence. There are n such subsequences in total.

I have no idea how to use those convergent subsequences to contruct one sigle convergent subsequence of $\{x_k\}$.

Thanks in advance. And I'm looking forward to a rigorous proof. That is, phrases such as "continuing in this way, after n steps, we obtain..." should be avoided. I'm sorry for this requirement but I really don't like this style of writing. Maybe this can be made into a rigrous proof using mathematical induction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way your proof is going, you need to take your subsequences one after the other; you get a first subsequence, then a subsequence of that one, etc. It's a finite process and there is no ambiguity about it. But if you don't want that, let's go another route.

Also, you don't say what your field is, so I'll assume it's $\mathbb R$.

Choose $k$ such that $\|x\|\leq k$ for all $x\in M$. Let $\varphi:\mathbb R^n\to X$ be the map
$$
\varphi(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)=\sum_j\alpha_je_j.
$$
This map is continuous, because it is linear and
$$
\|\varphi(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\|\leq\max\{\|e_j\|:\ j\}\,\sum_j|\alpha_j|\leq\max\{\|e_j\|:\ j\}\,n^{1/2}\,\Big(\sum_j|\alpha_j|^2\Big)^{1/2}.
$$
Let $R_0=\varphi^{-1}(M)$. Since $M$ is closed, then $R_0$ is closed. And for any $\alpha\in R_0$ we have
$$
\Big(\sum_j|\alpha_j|^2\Big)^{1/2}\leq\sum_j|\alpha_j|\leq\frac1c\,\|\varphi(\alpha)\|\leq\frac kc.
$$
So $R_0$ is bounded. Being a closed and bounded subset of $\mathbb R^n$, it is compact by Bolzano-Weierstrass. Hence $M=\varphi(R_0)$ is compact, being a continuous image of a compact set.

---

If you want to make the argument with the subsequences of subsequences idea, it can be done with a simple induction. Indeed, by Bolzano-Weierstrass $\{\alpha_1^{(k)}\}$ admits a convergent subsequence $\{\alpha_1^{(k_j)}\}$. Now assume as inductive argument that there exist increasing positive integers $m_1,m_2,\ldots$ such that $\{\alpha_1^{(m_j)}\}_j,\ldots,\{\alpha_r^{(m_j)}\}_j$ admit convergent sequences. Since the sequence $\{\alpha_{r+1}^{(m_j)}\}$ is bounded, it admits a convergent subsequence $\{\alpha_{r+1}^{(n_j)}\}$. As $\{n_j\}_j\subset \{m_j\}_j$, all the sequences $\{\alpha_1^{(m_j)}\}_j,\ldots,\{\alpha_{r+1}^{(m_j)}\}_j$ admit convergent sequences. By induction there exists an increasing sequence $\ell_j$ such that , $\{\alpha_1^{(\ell_j)}\}_j,\ldots,\{\alpha_n^{(\ell_j)}\}_j$ admit convergent sequences.

If we denote $\alpha_r=\lim_j\alpha_r^{(\ell_j)}$ and $x=\sum_r\alpha_re_r$, then
\begin{align}
\|x-x_j\|\leq\sum_{r=1}^n|\alpha_r-\alpha_r^{(\ell_j)}|\,\|e_j\|\xrightarrow[j\to\infty]{}0.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your method definitely makes sense. I came up with an idea to complete my own proof (i.e., selecting n subsequences step by step) in a rigorous manner and I have posted an answer. I would be happy if you could take a look at it. Best Regards.

Comment: I tried to read your argument, but I had a hard time following it. It looks too complicated and cumbersome for the task at hand. I have edited how I think it could be done into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was shocked when I saw your proof by mathematical induction. It's a simple and neat proof. Mine is complicated. However, I would like to explain what I had meant to do. I'm now quite confused.
You must know about the theorem which states that any infinite set must contain a countably infinite subset. In order to show this, we select an $x_1\in X$, and then an $x_2\in X\setminus\{x_1\}$, and then an $x_3\in X\setminus\{x_1,x_2\}$, and so forth. It's clear that $x_2$ depends on $x_1$, and $x_3$ depends on both $x_1$ and $x_2$, and so forth.

Comment: In order to rigorously prove this, we need a combination of the axiom of choice and the recursion theorem. More precisely, we first take a choice function $H$ on $P(X)\setminus\varnothing$, then define a sequence $\{S_k\}$ of subsets of $X$ recursively, and then define $x_n:=H(X\setminus S_n)$ as desired. I found these two questions SO similar to each other. Back to our question, we first choose a strictly increasing function  $f_1$ so that $\{\alpha^{f_1(k)}_1\}$ is convergent, and then there is some strictly increasing function $f_2$ such that $\{\alpha^{f_1\circ f_2(k)}_2\}$ is covergent.

Comment: Continuing in this way, we use both recursive definition and the axiom of choice to obtain $f_1, f_2,\cdots,f_n$, and their composite $f_1\circ f_2\circ\cdots\circ f_n$ is the desired function, that is for each $1\leq r\leq n$, $\{\alpha^{f_1\circ\cdots\circ f_n}_r\}$ is convergent. This is basically what I did in my answer. The only difference is that we use "finite recursion" to construct a finite sequence $f_1,\cdots f_n$ in this question, while in that set theory question, we use infinite recursion to construct an infinite sequence $x_1,x_2,/cdots$.  They're just so similar!

Comment: This is why I was shocked when I saw your solution. It's so simple! However, I don't think mathematical induction could be used to prove that set theory question. Could you give me your opinion on these two questions? Their relation? Thanks a lot for your patience.

Comment: I'm possibly naive in my use of set theory, as I'm not used to paying close attention to the axioms. But as far as I can tell, you can prove the set theory result equally by induction. The way I would do it by induction, would be: take $X$ an infinite set. Let $x_1\in X$. Suppose that we have $x_1,\ldots,x_k\in X$. If $X\setminus\{x_1,\ldots,x_k\}=\varnothing$ then $X$ would be finite. So there exists $x_{k+1}\in X\setminus\{x_1,\ldots,x_{k}\}$. This gives us a function $\gamma:\mathbb N\to X$ by $\gamma(k)=x_k$. This $\gamma$ is injective because by construction $x_k\ne x_j$ if $k\ne j$.

Comment: As I understand it, mathematical induction is used to prove that a certain property holds for a collection of integers (e.g., for all $n\geq 1$).  In my opinion, you are not using induction to define the function $\gamma :\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$. Instead you are using recursion (more precisely, the recursion theorem in set theory). Because one must provide a property P(n) when using induction.

Comment: For instance, when you prove that there exists an increasing sequence $\ell_j$ such that $\{\alpha^{(\ell_j)}_1\}_j\cdots\{\alpha^{(\ell_j)}_n\}_j$ admit convergent sequences in your answer, I think you're implicitly assuming a property "$P(r): r\leq n\Rightarrow$ there exists an increasing sequence $\ell_j$ such that $\{\alpha^{(\ell_j)}_1\}_j\cdots\{\alpha^{(\ell_j)}_r\}_j$ admit convergent sequences." Then you use the standard method to show that $P(r)$ holds for all $r\geq n$.

Comment: What I mean to say is, I don't think mathematical induction could be used to show that the injection $\gamma :\mathbb{N}\rightarrow X$ exists. Instead, $\gamma$ is defined recursively. And the increasing sequence $\ell_j$ could be defined recursively, too. This is what I did in my answer (despite the fact that it seems much more cumbersome). I'm suprised at the fact that the existence of $\ell_j$ could be showed by mathematical induction, while the existence of $\gamma$ could not. I hope I'm understanding it correctly, and thanks for your patience. (r≥n should be r≥1 in my last comment)

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Like I said, I never felt strong in axiomatic set theory. But if we follow for instance Halmos' *Naive Set Theory*, the recursion theorem is available in the usual ZFC. So in the end it is a matter of language right? If I replace "induction" with "recursion", then the argument in my comment holds.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because I couldn't find a rigorous way to complete the proof. More precisely, I was uncomfortable with phrases such as "following this pattern, after n steps, we obtain the desired subsequence...". Now I have managed to overcome this problem and I'm writing down my solution for those who are intrested in it. Any corrections and suggestions for improvement are most welcome.

We know that

$x_1=\alpha_1^{1}e_1+\alpha_2^{1}e_2+...+\alpha_n^{1}e_n$,

$x_2=\alpha_1^{2}e_1+\alpha_2^{2}e_2+...+\alpha_n^{2}e_n$,

...

$x_k=\alpha_1^{k}e_1+\alpha_2^{k}e_2+...+\alpha_n^{k}e_n$,

...

And for each $1\leq r\leq n$, the sequence $\{\alpha^{k}_r\}$ is bounded in the field $\mathbb{F}$ ($\mathbb{F}$ is either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$)(we can show this result using that lemma). Thus each sequence contains a convergent subsequence by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. In particular, $\{\alpha^{k}_1\}$ contains a subsequence $\{\alpha^{f_1(k)}_1\}$, where $f_1$ is a strictly increasing function from $\mathbb{Z}^+$ to $\mathbb{Z}^+$ (That's how subsequences are defined).

Then the corresponding sequence $\{\alpha^{f_1(k)}_2\}$ is a subsequence of $\{\alpha^{k}_2\}$, not necessarily convergent, but bounded. Then there is a strictly increasing function $f_2:\mathbb{Z}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\{\alpha^{f_1(f_2(k))}_2\}$ is convergent by Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Let $A:=\{\ell\in{\mathbb{Z}^+}^{\mathbb{Z}^+}:\ell$ is strictly increasing$\}$. Thus intuitively speaking (not a strict treatment), continuing in this way, after n steps, we are able to find the following functions

$f_1\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\ell(k)}_1\}$ is convergent$\}=S_1$,

$f_2\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{f_1(\ell(k))}_2\}$ is convergent$\}=S_2$,

$f_3\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{f_1(f_2(\ell(k)))}_3\}$ is convergent$\}=S_3$,

...

$f_n\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{f_{1}\circ f_{2}\circ\cdots\circ f_{n-1} 
(\ell(k))}_n\}$ is convergent$\}=S_n$.

It's easy to see that we need a combination of the Recursion Theorem and the Axiom of Choice.

Since all of the desired $S_r$'s are subsets of $A$. Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a choice function on $\mathscr{P}(A)\setminus \{\varnothing\}$. In other words, $\mathcal{H}:\mathscr{P}(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}\rightarrow A$, $\forall S\in\mathscr{P}(A)\setminus\{\varnothing\}$, $\mathcal{H}(S)\in S$.

Once we determine $S_1,\cdots ,S_n$, we can then put $f_1:=\mathcal{H}(S_1),\cdots ,f_n:=\mathcal{H}(S_n)$.

Let $I$ denote the identity map on $\mathbb{Z}^+$. It's easy to see that in order to construct $S_1,\cdots ,S_n$, we need to decide the following $\Lambda_r$'s ($1\leq r\leq n$).

$f_1\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\overbrace{I}^{\Lambda_1:=I}(\ell(k))}_1\}$ is convergent$\}=S_1$,

$f_2\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\overbrace{f_1}^{\Lambda_2:=\Lambda_1\circ f_1}(\ell(k))}_2\}$ is convergent$\}=S_2$,

$f_3\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\overbrace{f_1\circ f_2}^{\Lambda_3:=\Lambda_2\circ f_2}(\ell(k))}_3\}$ is convergent$\}=S_3$,

...

$f_n\in\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\overbrace{f_{1}\circ f_{2}\circ\cdots\circ f_{n-1}}^{\Lambda_n:=\Lambda_{n-1}\circ f_n}(\ell(k))}_n\}$ is convergent$\}=S_n$.

Here is the recursion theorem we'll use to constrcut $\Lambda_1,\cdots ,\Lambda_n$:

*(Finite Recursion Theorem) Let $S$ be a set, let $s_0$ be an element in $S$, and let $J:\mathbb{Z}^+\times S\rightarrow S$. Then for every $m\geq 1$, there is a unique function $D:\{1,\cdots ,m\}\rightarrow S$ such that $D(1)=s_0$ and $D(k+1)=J(k,D(k))$ for all $1\leq k\leq m-1$.*

This theorem is quite intuitive and can be proved using mathematical induction. Although it could be modified to be simpler to apply, I wouldn't change it as this is the version I first encountered in Terence Tao's textbook.

Now let's use this theorem to construct $\Lambda_1,\cdots,\Lambda_n$. But let's first find the pattern for the recursion formula.

$\Lambda_1=I$, $\Lambda_2=\Lambda_1\circ f_1$. Notice that $f_1$ is intended to be just

$\mathcal{H}(S_1)=\mathcal{H}($$\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\Lambda_1(\ell(k))}_1\}$ is convergent$\}$$)$

Thus $\Lambda_2=\Lambda_1\circ$$\mathcal{H}($$\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\Lambda_1(\ell(k))}_1\}$ is convergent$\}$$)$.

Similarly, for each $1\leq r\leq n-1$, we intend to obtain

$\Lambda_{r+1}=\Lambda_r\circ$$\mathcal{H}($$\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\Lambda_r(\ell(k))}_r\}$ is convergent$\}$$)=J(r,\Lambda_r)$($J$ is the function that appears in the recursion theorem and will be used to define $\Lambda_r$ once it is constructed).

Hence we define $J:\mathbb{Z}^+\times A\rightarrow A$ to be the function

$J(r,g) = \begin{cases}
g\circ\mathcal{H}(\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{g(l(k))}_r\}\text{is convergent}\}),& r\leq n\\
I,& r\gt n\\
\end{cases}$ for all $r\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ and all $g\in A$. This function is well-defined, as one could verify.

Since $n\geq 1$ ($n$ is the dimension and is assumed to be a positive integer here) there is a unique function $\Lambda:\{1,\cdots,n\}\rightarrow A$ such that $\Lambda_1=I$ and $\Lambda_{r+1}=J(r,\Lambda_r)=\Lambda_r\circ$$\mathcal{H}($$\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\Lambda_r(\ell(k))}_r\}$ is convergent$\}$$)$ for all $1\leq r\leq n-1$.

Now we are ready to define $f_1,\cdots,f_n$.

Let $f:\{1,\cdots,f_n\}\rightarrow A$ be the function defined by $f_r=\mathcal{H}(\{\ell\in A:\{\alpha^{\Lambda_r(\ell(k))}_r\text{is convergent}\})$ for all $1\leq r\leq n$.

$f$ is well-defined, as one could verify.

Intuitively speaking, $f_1\circ\cdots\circ f_n\in A$ is the function we need. But the "n times composition" is not rigorously established in this proof. However, it is clear that we can use $\Lambda_n\circ f_n$ as a substitue.

Clearly, $\Lambda_n\circ f_n\in A$, hence $\{\alpha^{\Lambda_n\circ f_n(k)}_r\}$ is a subsequence of $\{\alpha^k_r\}$ ($\forall 1\leq r\leq n$). Let's show that it's actually a convergent subsequence.

From the definition of $f$ we know that $\{\alpha^{\Lambda_r\circ f_r(k)}_r\}$ is convergent. Informally speaking, $\Lambda_r\circ f_r$ is just $f_1\circ\cdots\circ f_r$, and $(f_1\circ\cdots\circ f_r)\circ(f_{r+1}\circ\cdots\circ f_n)=\Lambda_n\circ f_n$. If $f_{r+1}\circ\cdots\circ f_n$ was rigorously established, then $\{\alpha^{\Lambda_n\circ f_n(k)}_r\}$ would become a subsequence of $\{\alpha^{\Lambda_r\circ f_r(k)}_r\}$, hence convergent.

This could be done using backwards induction.

Let P(r) be the property "$1\leq r\leq n\Longrightarrow$there is a $g\in A$ such that $(\Lambda_r\circ f_r)\circ g=\Lambda_n\circ f_n$". Let's prove that P(r) is true for all integer $r\leq n$.

First P(n) is true since $1\leq n\leq n$ and we can take $g$ to be the identity. Suppose inductively that $r\leq n$ and P(r) is true, let's prove P(r-1). Let's assume that $1\leq r-1\leq n$. If $r-1=n$, then P(r) is true for sure. If $r-1\leq n$, then $1\leq r\leq n$. We know from P(r) that there is a $g\in A$ such that $(\Lambda_r\circ f_r)\circ g=\Lambda_n\circ f_n$. But $\Lambda_r=\Lambda_{r-1}\circ f_{r-1}$, we have $\Lambda_{r-1}\circ f_{r-1}\circ(f_r\circ g)=\Lambda_n\circ f_n$. Completed.

For each $1\leq r\leq n$, let $y_r$ be the unique limit of $\{\alpha^{\Lambda_n\circ f_n(k)}_r\}$, which is in $\mathbb{F}$.

Finally, it remains to show that the subsequence $\{x_{\Lambda_n\circ f_n(k)}\}$ of $\{x_k\}$ converges to $y_1 e_1 +\cdots +y_n e_n\in M$. This can be accomplished by the usual "$\varepsilon-N$" argument.